# Including access token in endpoint URL when using named credential in REST callout

Tags: callout, oauth2, namedcredentials

I'm trying to retrieve a list of forms using the [FormAssembly API](https://github.com/veerwest/formassembly-api) via a HTTP Request to the endpoint:

https://app.formassembly.com/api_v1/forms/index.json

I was able to setup named credentials and an authentication provider to successfully authorize via oAuth 2.0.  I believe it was successful b/c the FA oauth flow was triggered, and my named credential has authentication status = 'Authenticated'.

FA specifies that the access token must be included as a query string parameter, as follows

https://app.formassembly.com/api_v1/forms/index.json?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

In the developer documentation on "[Merge Fields for Apex Callouts That Use Named Credentials](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_named_credentials_merge_fields.htm)", it seems that one can access the Access Token using {!$Credential.OAuthToken}.

However, I have been unable to add this variable to the endpoint URL.  The example in the docs is for the request header, so I'm not sure if its just not possible to do this, or if I'm doing something wrong.

This approach results in a 'variable does not exist' error in Salesforce

- `req.setEndpoint('callout:TFA/api_v1/forms/index.json?access_token='+{!$Credential.OAuthToken});`

Passing the variable inside quotes, which is similar to the approach in the documentation, gives `System.CalloutException: The URI is invalid.`

- `req.setEndpoint('callout:TFA/api_v1/forms/index.json?access_token={!$Credential.OAuthToken}');`

This approach gives an 'invalid access token' response from FA

- `req.setEndpoint('callout:TFA/api_v1/forms/index.json');`

I've tried including the access token in the header with the endpoint above, but I still get invalid access token from FA, as its expecting it in the endpoint URL itself

- `req.setHeader('Authorization', 'access_token {!$Credential.OAuthToken}');`

So, is there a way to get at the access token so I can include it in the URL itself?  And, are there any security concerns with sending the access token in the endpoint in this manner?

My code is copied below.  I'm currently just calling it via anonymous apex for testing.

```
public class TFA_Endpoint {

    public void callTFA(){
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();        
        // variable does not exist req.setEndpoint('callout:TFA/api_v1/forms/index.json?access_token='+{!$Credential.OAuthToken});
        req.setEndpoint('callout:TFA/api_v1/forms/index.json');
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'access_token {!$Credential.OAuthToken}');       
        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
        System.debug(res.getBody());
    }

}
```

UPDATE - FEB 2019.  Not a solution to the original issue, but i dug into it further w/ formassembly and they have some funky requirements, but if you set the auth header as below, it will work

```
req.setHeader('Authorization','Token ="{!$Credential.OAuthToken}"');
```

Comment: Hey Gorav - what settings did you use on your Auth. Provider record?  I assume you left "Send Access Token in Header" unchecked?

Comment: thanks David, i tried a bunch of combinations of auth provider settings and named credential settings.  always ended w/ an invalid access token error.  changing the auth provider settings didnt seem to impact my ability to connect via oauth initially when i saved the named credential - that was successful every time.  but when i would try to hit the named credential via callout, i would get invalid access token b/c its expecting it in the URL.

Comment: Sorry I don't have any other ideas.  I've never been able to use Named Credentials for my projects because I couldn't configure a proper Auth. Provider, so I had to write the authorization methods and store the secrets and tokens in custom settings and platform cache.

Comment: @gorav, I am stuck in same issue. Were you able to come up with any solution?

Comment: Negative, never found a solution.  I suppose there would be some way to call out to sfdc and capture the token, but...that's just fantasy for me...

Comment: @gorav if I am not mistaken, the header should be `Authorization: Bearer token`. Have you tried using something like `req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer {!$Credential.OAuthToken}');` ?