# Using Named Credential + OpenID Connect auth provider to obtain access token with client_credentials grant

Tags: apex, callout, oauth2, authentication, namedcredentials

I am trying to use the Named credentials for the first time without using the named credentials directly if I call the endpoints with credentials it works perfectly fine  which uses OAuth where I get the Bearer/Access token from Microsoft and use them to post the data to the external system like below

```
@future (callout=true)
public static void createSegmentD365(String subSegmentID) {
    String clientId = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
    String clientSecret = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
    String tenant_id = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
    String resource = 'https://dev.cloudax.dynamics.com';

    String reqbody = 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id='+clientId+'&client_secret='+clientSecret+'&tenant_id='+tenant_id+'&resource='+resource;

    Http h = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setBody(reqbody);
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setEndpoint('https://login.microsoftonline.com/abc.org/oauth2/token');
    HttpResponse res = h.send(req);

    deserializeResponse resp1 = (deserializeResponse)JSON.deserialize(res.getbody(),deserializeResponse.class);
    String bearerToken = resp1.access_token;     

    JSON2Apex js = new JSON2Apex();
    js.dataAreaId = 'jax';
    js.SegmentCode = subSegmentID;

    String jsonBody = json.serialize(js);    

    Http http1 = new Http();
    HttpRequest req1 = new HttpRequest();


    req1.setEndpoint('https://dev.cloudax.dynamics.com/data/parentAccounts');
    req1.setMethod('POST');
    req1.setTimeout(20000);
    req1.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+bearerToken);
    req1.setBody(jsonBody);
    req1.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
    HttpResponse res1 = http1.send(req1);
   }
```

I am trying to use the named credentials now. I set the AUTH Provider and Named Credentials and I get the Authenticated status in the Named Credentials like below

[image]

So I changed the Apex Callout like

```
   @future (callout=true)
   public static void createSegmentD365(String subSegmentID) {
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint('callout:D365Credential/data/parentAccounts');
    req.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer {!$D365Credential.access_token}');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setTimeout(20000);
    req.setBody(jsonBody);
    Http http = new Http();
    HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
    System.debug('Response Body=========' + res.getBody());
```

In the debug I get the Authentication failed, not sure what I am missing here any help is greatly appreciated

[image]

Comment: You didn't provide request/response from Postman, tough to know what you did there. Based on your Apex snippet, the `String reqbody = ...` line of code is not equivalent to your auth provider configuration.

Comment: @identigral Added the screenshot of the Postman. I am able to successfully call the endpoints without using named credentials with my above apex callout

Comment: When you acquire the token from `login.microsoftonline.com`, you have all these parameters in your Postman and Apex snippet. Where are they in the Named Credential?

Comment: How do we give them, I tried to add to the Authorization endpoint URL like ?grant_type=client_credentials&tenant_id=xxxxxxx&resource=https://dev.cloudax.dynamics.com which doesnt let the Authentication to be successful looks like it will use my username/password to authenticate instead of the Client id/client secret. I dont have access  to the application

Comment: OpenId Connect auth. provider does not support `grant_type=client_credentials`. This is undocumented..but similar questions have been answered on this forum that explain that. That aside, some parameters can be appended and this is [documented](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_provider_openid_connect.htm&type=5). Whether appending some of these parameters will or will not be useful depends on the target service (Microsoft in this case). Sounds like you're better off with Apex..

Comment: @user81642 does Auth Provider support client_credentials? I Can see on the screenshot , you have got the authentication successful.

Answer (score 5):

This line is not needed when using [named credentials as callout endpoints](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_named_credentials.htm):

```
req.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer {!$D365Credential.access_token}');
```

### From the example

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('callout:My_Named_Credential/some_path');
req.setMethod('GET');
Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
System.debug(res.getBody());
```

### Note

I was able to find [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/203274/including-access-token-in-endpoint-url-when-using-named-credential-in-rest-callo) which shows that form assembly has some funky requirements. If you absolutely need to include this header for some reason, I think you're using the wrong merge field. [This documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_named_credentials_merge_fields.htm) shows that it should `OAuthToken` instead of `access_token`.

```
req.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer {!$D365Credential.OAuthToken}');
```

Comment: I did both recommendation tried to remove the setHeader also changed from the access_token to OAuthToken both the ways I am getting error `NAMED_CREDENTIAL_REQUEST NamedCallout[Name=D365Credential, Endpoint=https://dev.cloudax.dynamics.com/data/parentAccounts, Method=POST, External Credential Type=EXTERNAL, HTTP Header Authorization=Method: Bearer - Authorization Credential Hash: -635680243, Retry on 401=True]`

Comment: Is there any way to debug the OAuthToken generated I tried `System.debug('{!$D365Credential.OAuthToken}');` doesnt work it treats it as a String

Comment: The merge fields will only work when part of http requests, otherwise as you see it will use it as a string. Our org uses a host of named credentials and we have never had an issue, if the above does not work for you, contact the vendor you are trying to connect to and ask for assistance. They may require additional information that is not provided out of the box as in the above case with FormAssembly.

Comment: Thank you, point is we are able to connect to the vendor directly without the Named Credentials passing in the Req body and Authorization header as I shown above

Comment: Seems like the merge field should be `AuthorizationHeaderValue`?

Comment: @AdrianLarson very possible. I've never personally had to use the merge fields. Questions I would have are does it include the "bearer" part or just the token? could something like `req.setHeader('Authorization','{!$Credential.AuthorizationMethod} {!$Credential.AuthorizationHeaderValue}');` Be valid? I would expect that if you do not specify the header, a header would be generated in a simmilar manner making this somewhat unnecessary.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I tried changing the `AuthorizationHeaderValue` I still get UnAuthorized 401 error.. have used grant_type `client_credentials` with the named credentials?

Comment: @user81642 the credential you have in the screenshot uses oauth, you should not be using client_credentials defined anywhere in your callout. IM also noticing that you do not have "allow merge fields in header" selected in your named credential, make sure that is checked.

Comment: @gNerb I am sorry I am not getting you.. My question is how do I use named credentials with client_credentials.

Comment: Change the "oauth 2" in your named credential to "password authentication" That being said, I would not do that. it is less secure and you don't need to do it, if you authenciated successfully with oauth you should use oauth