# Named credential using OpenId Auth Provider

Tags: oauth2, namedcredentials, auth-provider

Is it possible to setup Named Credentials for following type of OAuth provider? I tried configuration named credential and Auth Provider (using OpenId) but unable to authenticate successfully.

"grant_type":"client_credentials",

"client_id": "*********************",

"client_secret": "************************",

"scope": "Applicable Scope ",

"endUserAgentIP":"",

"endUserAgentID":"",

"userType":"guest"

Comment: OpenId Connect auth. provider does not support `grant_type=client_credentials`

Comment: Not sure how this person managed to do the same? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/307471/using-named-credential-openid-connect-auth-provider-to-obtain-access-token-wit